# Content-type for JHipster getAllEntities API

Tags: arrays, json, jhipster

I am asking for getAllDevelopers using Swagger API for guidance and Response Content Type says "application/json". The results I get for my Developer entity is like so:

```
[
  Developer{id=1001, name='David L. Whitehurst'}, 
  Developer{id=1002, name='Matt Raible'}, 
  Developer{id=1003, name='Eugene Cuirana'}, 
  Developer{id=1004, name='Ryan Hoegg'}, 
  Developer{id=1005, name='Don Brown'}, 
  Developer{id=1006, name='Harry Houdini'}, 
  Developer{id=1007, name='Howie Mandell'}
]
```

When I run this or check it at jsonlint.com it say's it's not valid JSON. I found this using Jersey client to make a request against the API. I'm mapping JSON objects to POJOs. I was getting a deserialization error.

Is the response supposed to be valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This response is not valid JSON as you have guessed.
It should have been like this:

```
[
  {"id":1001, "name":"David L. Whitehurst"}, 
  {"id":1002, "name":"Matt Raible"}, 
  {"id":1003, "name":"Eugene Cuirana"}, 
  {"id":1004, "name":"Ryan Hoegg"}, 
  {"id":1005, "name":"Don Brown"}, 
  {"id":1006, "name":"Harry Houdini"}, 
  {"id":1007, "name":"Howie Mandell"}
]
```

Your response seems to be a `toString()` on a `List<Developer>`.

Does the JHipster pages for Developer entity work as expected?
If so, you should see the real JSON response in browser's console and compare also the request.

Comment: The generated code works fine. I'll check everything closely and if it needs correction, I'll see if I can fix it or put in an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution for my RestController and it produces valid JSON, however, the code is actually generated by Yeoman and I want to find out how one of the contributors would like to fix it. I'll create the issue and I'll probably try to fix it but there's a Yeoman learning curve in front of me. Also, the new response JSON is after the Java code.

```
    /**
     * GET  /developers -> get all the developers.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/developers",   
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>> getAllDevelopers(Pageable pageable)
        throws URISyntaxException, JSONException {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Developers");
        Page<Developer> page = developerRepository.findAll(pageable); 
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/developers");

        // dlwhitehurst quick-fix, this is Yo-generated code

        List<JSONObject> developers = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (Developer n : page.getContent()) {
            JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
            try {
                entity.put("id", n.getId());
                entity.put("name", n.getName());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            developers.add(entity);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(developers, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Modified JSON Response (Valid)

```
[{
    "name": "David L. Whitehurst",
    "id": 1001
}, {
    "name": "Matt Raible",
    "id": 1002
}, {
    "name": "Eugene Cuirana",
    "id": 1003
}, {
    "name": "Ryan Hoegg",
    "id": 1004
}, {
    "name": "Don Brown",
    "id": 1005
}, {
    "name": "Harry Houdini",
    "id": 1006
}, {
    "name": "Howie Mandell",
    "id": 1007
}]
```

Comment: This is not what you should do, you're not supposed to use JSONObject in your controller, JSON serialization is Jackson's responsibility. If you get wrong response, it's probably because you sent wrong request. If you go to api docs page in your JHipster app, you will see the curl command options to use.

Comment: You are correct. I had tested this in a terminal with CURL initially and it must have been correct then. I annotated my end with Jackson and my Jersey client request must have somehow caused the Response (in my running JHipster app terminal) to prefix the JSON objects somehow with "Developer". I'm not sure how I was able to get the JSON coming from the Rest controller in the Spring boot application to actually send that way.